# Select Count days between two dates using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql

I need to get the number of holidays between two dates. I have tried using the query below but I'm getting an incorrect count number.

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 01/2/2022 | 03/2/2022 |
| 17/2/2022 | 19/2/2022 |

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
WHERE StartDate <= '02/2/2022' and EndDate >= '19/2/2022'
```

how I make this date => '02/2/2022' return count of day that between two dates from the first row from the table and get count day from the second row.

The count must be 5 days.

Comment: Isn't it easier to search before asking a redundant question.  Q: tsql get hollydays between 2 dates => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803823/calculating-number-of-holidays-between-two-dates-in-table-using-sql

Comment: @Fildor I deleted my incorrect comments.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle No, it's not clear to me, if you see the table and query you find select must be started from '2/2/2022', and this date found between '1/2/2022' and '3/2/2022',

Comment: I often try to get the query to work as desired in Access Query Interface. Ince it works there I transfer into my software however appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it is to have a table that has one row per day for every day from eg year 2000 to year 2099, then you can:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
  cal           --your dates table
  INNER JOIN h. --your holiday table 
  ON cal.d BETWEEEN h.start AND h.end
WHERE
  cal.d BETWEEN '2022-02-02' AND '2022-02-19'
```

The join will produce 6 rows, the where trims it to 5, there is your count

Generating the calendar table, or its equivalent (an arbitrary series of dates) is an exercise for the reader.. See something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835334/how-to-create-recursive-query-to-get-all-dates-between-two-dates)